# G Suite Developer Hub Error - "Something Went Wrong"

Tags: google-apps-script

When I connect to "script.google.com" (via Chrome) to access my projects, I am getting the following error;
"Something Went Wrong - Please reload the page to try again".

I do the reload but keep getting the same error.

I have tried logging out of Google and back in, shutting down Chrome and starting again but the error still remains.  This was working for me less than 24 hours ago and none of my projects are currently listed which concerns me.

What can I do/try to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This appears to be a bug!

This was affecting me for a while, though it seems to have rectified itself now. This seemed to go on for maybe a week or two.

That being said, I have taken the liberty of reporting this on Google's Issue Tracker for you, detailing the behaviour:

- [G Suite Developer Hub Displaying "Something went wrong"](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147468046)

You can hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the page which lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.